# mysql OR request returns just the first half but not the second

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty sure this has been answered before but I cannot seem to find it.

I have a mysql request, and it is returning only the first half's results as opposed to all of them as an array.

```
sql= "SELECT filename, name, keywords FROM `pics` WHERE (keywords LIKE '%chair%' OR '%jeff%') ORDER BY date ASC";

$rows = $db->fetch_all_array($sql);
foreach($rows as $i => $record){
```

So if I were to run the above code, I get all entries with `chair` in them but not with `jeff`... if I switch them around and do `'%jeff%' OR '%chair%'` I get all entries with `jeff` in them but not with `chair`

I am sure I am missing something that is needed with the `OR` but I cannot figure it out

Comment: keywords LIKE '%chair%' OR keywords LIKE '%jeff%'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`keywords LIKE '%chair%' OR keywords LIKE '%jeff%'`

You need to OR the entire condition.

Comment: Ah you all are bloddy genius's

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau, no we just know how to read the manual :-)

Comment: It's called experience. We all started with queries like that that didn't work. (And anyone that says otherwise is lying.)

Comment: @Robbie and when you did that, did you then check the manual first, or post on some forum?

Comment: Copied other people's code and bucket loads of trail and error if I can't find Ann example to copy. I've been using relational databases for over 25 years, forums didn't exist then like they do now. Having said that, I still get queries wrong and prefer to trial/debug myself and use the manual than go to a forum. Better learning that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should put 'keywords LIKE' before '%jeff%'

So, "keywords LIKE '%chair%' or keywords LIKE '%jeff%'"

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in the column name for each item you want to look for. So in your example this should work:

```
$sql= "SELECT filename, name, keywords 
       FROM `pics` 
       WHERE (`keywords` LIKE '%chair%' OR `keyword`s LIKE '%jeff%') 
       ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WHERE (keywords LIKE '%chair%' OR keywords LIKE '%jeff%')
```